# How do I remove a file with no permissions?

Tags: linux, permissions, filesystems

A hacker has dropped a file in my tmp dir that is causing issues. Nothing malicious except creating GB's of error_log entries because their script is failing. However, the file they are using to execute has no permissions and even as ROOT I can't delete or rename this file.

```
----------  1 wwwusr wwwusr 1561 Jan 19 02:31 zzzzx.php

root@servername [/home/wwwusr/public_html/tmp]# rm zzzzx.php
rm: remove write-protected regular file './zzzzx.php'? y
rm: cannot remove './zzzzx.php': Operation not permitted
```

I have also tried removing by inode

```
root@servername [/home/wwwusr/public_html/tmp]# ls -il

...
1969900 ----------  1 wwwusr wwwusr 1561 Jan 19 02:31 zzzzx.php

root@servername [/home/wwwusr/public_html/tmp]# find . -inum 1969900 -exec rm -i {} \;

rm: remove write-protected regular file './zzzzx.php'? y
rm: cannot remove './zzzzx.php': Operation not permitted
```

How do I delete this file?

Comment: Were I you, I'd be looking to [nuke and pave](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nuke%20n%20pave) that box. It clearly has at least one security hole, which is bad enough that someone can write new files *with custom permissions* outside the document root, and then on top of all that, manage to get PHP/Apache to try and load it. My friend, you are royally pwned. If you want that box back, you've got to [nuke it from orbit. It's the only way to be sure](http://goo.gl/Y5WHr).

Comment: Thanks Warren. This is actually a brand new box moving over accounts that have never been compromised before. I'm trying to figure out what the settings are that are different (both CPanel boxes).

Comment: Just because the OS is recent and the install fresh doesn't mean you cannot have a compromise. A bug detected today in an OS that shipped 6 months ago may persist for years, as people continue to install the older OS from CDs that are continually getting older. Even if there is a patch for the flaw, the window between installation and update allows the compromise. Setting that aside, if I am wrong that some bad actor placed that file on your system, a conscientious sysadmin would have to at least try to explain its presence in another way.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The file has probably been locked using [file attributes](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_chattr.htm).

As root, do

```
lsattr zzzzx.php
```

Attributes `a` (append mode) or `i` (immutable) present would prevent your `rm`. If they're there, then

```
chattr -ai zzzzx.php
rm zzzzx.php
```

should delete your file.

Comment: I would avoid calling them _extended_ file attributes, as it could cause confusion with the extended file attributes as set with `setfxattr` and used to store ACL or SELinux... attributes.

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas - ok. Does plain 'file attributes' work for you?

Comment: I can't think of anything better. They used to be ext2 file attributes but they are now supported by other FS on Linux like xfs of btrfs, so one can no longer call them that.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately Warren didn't post as an answer but as a comment; I can't emphasise enough that he's totally correct.

Removing/changing one file won't fix your REAL problem; it will make ONE symptom go away.  Take the box offline, take an image for later forensics, and re-install, with a newer version (hopefully w/ new security fixes) of whatever you were running.

I repeat: deleting the file is **NOT A FIX**.

Comment: I didn't post an answer because my comment doesn't answer the asked question.

Comment: Heh ... I guess I'm still too new to the stackexchange way of doing things.  I'd rather get down voted for "not answering" than not saying what needs to be said ;D

Comment: The question isn't about fixing that problem, it's about removing a file with no permissions.  And it's an interesting question!

Comment: @tink: That's what comments are *for*: to say things that need to be said, which are not answers to the question.

Comment: Obviously this *does* answer the question that was asked. Wiping the disk will remove the file! Ordinarily it is not a reasonable method of removing a file, but in this case, it is the *most* reasonable way, because it solves the underlying problem at the same time. (Furthermore, even if this did not literally answer the question as it was explicitly asked--which it does!--it's not wrong to post a solution to an OP's [actual problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/185080).)